# Se puede agregar una directiva de Angular por Script?

Tags: jquery, angular5, angular-directivas

Lo que trato es de agregar la directiva `ng-checked` en una etiqueta `<a>` con **JQuery** ya que utilizo **Bootstrap Material Design** y este me hace que no me trabaje dicha directiva mensionada, ya que este el CheckBox es redefinido por algun Script. Al tratar de hacer algo como esto:

```
<div class="switch">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="myRadio"> Active
    </label>
</div>
```

`ng-checked="myRadio"` aparece tal cual en el html. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Angular o AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer ng-checked no exite para Angular, sino para AngularJS. Lo cual el codigo quedaria

```
<div class="switch">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="myRadio"> Active
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

No puedes hacer eso, antes de generar el codigo HTML puro Angular.js compila todas las directivas y templates. Para hacer una modificación de las directivas o agregar nuevos templates al objeto del DOM es necesario utilizar la libreria $compile, echale un vistazo.

Pero a tu respuesta, No, no se puede meter una directiva angular por JQuery y que funcione.